# How to get Nunit Test Adapter Framework working with .netcore 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

I seem to get this error when building my nunit project with .netcoreapp 3.1 and I can't figure out what mismatch version I have.  I noticed a similar post on here but with a difference, where it said i should have a Nunit and UnitTestAdapter version 3.9.0 but VS won't allow me to rollback and I don't see why I would need to anyway.  Error when buidling my solution is:

Any help in trying to resolve this error would be appreciated?

```
Package 'NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework 2.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, 
.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, 
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. 
This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

How can NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework 2.0.0 not be compatible with project when I have the latest packages?

My test.csproj is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="App1.config" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Chromium.ChromeDriver" Version="2.37.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.90" />
    <PackageReference Include="DapperExtensions" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExtentReports" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.11.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver" Version="85.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.8.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic" Version="1.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.NUnit" Version="3.8.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.8.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="WebDriverChromeDriver" Version="2.10.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a .net CORE library, with a .net FRAMEWORK project.

Comment: Should I omit the .netcore library then? If so how to do? Using VS by the way.

Comment: Sorry, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework/) 2.0.0 is a .net **framework** package (that is only supported by NUnit 2.6), and you are creating a .net **core** application.

Seeing as the last update for NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework was related to VS2015, I would suggest you find a different package.

I wonder if you just chose the wrong NUnit test adapter.

Comment: Perfect, not sure why I had it in there in the first place as can run my tests quite easily without it bearing in mind I am using v2019 anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that package at all. As [its description says](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework/), it's only for NUnit2 projects running in Visual Studio 2012. NUnit 2 is at least 5 years old.

The NUnit documentation site explains how to use NUnit in .NET Core in [.NET Core and .NET Standard](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/getting-started/dotnet-core-and-dotnet-standard.html). Add the latest versions of `NUnit`, `NUnit3TestAdapter` and `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`.

In your `csproj` file you should add :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.9.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.9.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After that you can run tests in Visual Studio or the command line with:

```
dotnet test
```

**Update**

Looks like your `csproj` already has the correct packages. In this case you only need to *remove* the obsolete package

Answer (score 0):

@Neil's pointed article explains it well.
Make sure your project targets .Net Core 3.x framework or up. If it's .NET Standard based project then the unit tests won't run. Here what it says:

- .NET Standard is like a Portable library in that it does not target
  any specific platform, but can run on any supported platform.
  Microsoft decided that your tests should be compiled to target a
  platform so they know which platform to run your tests under and you
  get the behavior you expect for the platform you are targeting.