# How to get the compatible list of packages between .NET Framework and .NET Core 6

Tags: .net, .net-core

We are migrating some unit tests running on the .NET framework (`NUnitTestAdapterWithFramework`) to run on .NET Core 6.

I'm looking for package list which needs to be replaced to be able to successfully migrate to .NET Core 6

To be specific: which package/method in .NET Core 6 would replace `NUnitTestMethod`?

I referred to https://www.nuget.org/ but not getting how to search for specific method

Is there any way to get the list of packages for .NET Core 6 and how we can replace them with .NET Framework?

Please suggest
EDIT 1 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{6EDF06}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>NUnitRetry</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>NUnitRetry</AssemblyName>
      <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
      <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\..\..\Vendor\NUnit\v2.6\addins\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.9.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.9.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: What versions of NUnit are you using (before & after)? The latest (currently v3.13.3) is compatible with .NET Framework 3.5, 4.0 & 4.5 as well as .NetStandard 2.0 which means it's okay for .NET 6.

Comment: What does `NUnitTestMethod` do? I'm used to just writing `[Test]` on test methods, and have done that for decades... I can't find any references to `NUnitTestMethod` online. If you want to see an example of a project which uses NUnit and runs on .NET 6, you could look at the test projects in my [Noda Time](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime) project - for example, https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/tree/main/src/NodaTime.Test (check out the dependencies in the project file).

Comment: Ooh, `NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework` is a different package that hasn't been updated since 2015 and definitely not ready for .Net 6. Take a look at this question and some of the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486089/how-to-get-nunit-test-adapter-framework-working-with-netcore-3-1. It could be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Nunit Test Adapter Framework working with .netcore 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486089/how-to-get-nunit-test-adapter-framework-working-with-netcore-3-1)

Comment: Thanks for all comments : I tried the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486089/how-to-get-nunit-test-adapter-framework-working-with-netcore-3-1
but it did not work. I mean , solution provided in that link is not working for me

Comment: NUnitTestMethod is part of NUnit.core 
In my CSPROJ file , I have made all changes required for dotnet core 6 (TargetFrameworkVersion)
and now tests are giving errors

Comment: Please see EDIT 1 , the CSPROJ file

Comment: Please suggest , how can I find replacement for NUnitTestMethod